# DataTables column.visible hides the first column despite returning true

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using Data Tables and jQuery right now. I have a simple table that has settings that are toggled via checkbox. When the setting is clicked (checked), I get the elements `attr('data-column')` and use that to either show or hide that table column based on what the user wants.

This works when the user selects a setting by using the following code:

```
// User clicks on a checkbox to toggle a setting on/off
$('.setting').click(function(){

  let table = $('#my-table');

  const current_element = $('input[name="test"][type="checkbox"]');
  const data_column_number = current_element.attr('data-column');

  if(current_element.is(":checked")){
    current_element.prop('checked',false);
    table.column(data_column_number).visible(false);
  }
  else {
    current_element.prop('checked',true);
    table.column(data_column_number).visible(true);
  }

});
```

Now, I have the user's pre-saved settings in a JSON array. I iterate through the array, and if a setting is checked I make the column number visible (`visible(true)`). If the setting should not be checked I set it's visible attribute to false (`visible(false)`). It looks like this:

```
let table = $('#my-table');

// assume value has an index called ['checked'] that is empty or set to 'checked'
$.each(settings,function(key,value){
  let current_element = $('input[name="'+key+'"][type="checkbox"]');
  let data_column_number = current_element.attr('data-column');

  if(value['checked'] === 'checked'){
    current_element.prop('checked',true);
    if(table.column(data_column_number).visible() === false){
      table.column(data_column_number).visible(true);
    }
  }
  else {
    current_element.prop('checked',false);
    if(table.column(data_column_number).visible() === true){
      table.column(data_column_number).visible(false);
    }
  }
});
```

For whatever reason, the code block above works except for the first `data-column`. I've used `console.log` to print out each `data-column` and to see what the values before and after `table.column(data_column_number).visible()` are and they are correct.

So if I check `"test"`, and then click something to load settings where `"test"` is enabled within those settings, it will hide `"test"` despite console.log showing that the `data-column` is `0` (correct), that `visible()` is set to `true` before any change (correct) and that `visible()` is still set to `true` by the end of the `$.each()` loop. Despite this, my first column disappears.

If my settings hide another column that is not at position 0, it works though.

Does anyone see what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. This might not apply to everyone, but just in case, make sure that the attribute `data-column` is **not** `undefined`. What was happening in my case was that somewhere down the line I had sub-items in the table, so some headings had no `data-column` attribute.

The way data tables works (at least in my case) was that setting an `undefined` column's visible status to either `true` or `false`, in essence, calling `table.column(undefined).visible(false)` or `table.column(undefined).visible(true)` would set `table.column(0).visible(false)`, no matter what.

Just adding a check to see if `data_column_number !== undefined` before proceeding with setting a `visible` state eliminated my issue.